# How do I manage to give answers again?

Tags: support, edits

I have to edit my answers, since I can not currently give answers to https://www.stackoverflow.com. Unfortunately, I cannot find my answers again ... How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Do you see anything here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/11856883

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You deleted an answer and others were deleted by moderators for various reasons:

You [should be able to see them because they're all newer than 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/11856883); but here they are for posterity:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292259/16587 - Deleted by you
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292402/16587 - Deleted by a moderator as it is a   comment, not an answer
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288674/16587 - deleted because the text is in German
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57287882/16587 - Deleted because it's a "Link only" answer (the answer contains a link, but no other information).
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275360/16587 - This could be an answer?  Not sure. it was deleted as "Not an answer".

In order to become un-answer blocked; you'll need to improve those answers.  For link only, that means including more information than just a link. Relevant text or code from that link, and you customizing it to fit the OP's question. For the non-english answer, it looks like you should be able to change that text to English and flag it for undeletion.

As always, after you've improved your answers that were deleted by a moderator, you'll need to flag them for moderator attention and let us know you want them undeleted and why they should be undeleted.

Another note, deleted posts count towards a post ban if they are zero or negatively scored. That's something to keep in mind when deciding to self-delete a post.